# XML InnerText Not Working in SQL WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: c#, xml

I have a table in SQL Server. One of the columns in this table holds XML data (ntext) like this:

```
<data>
<id>123</id>
<title>This is the title</title>
</data>
```

I then have some C# code that gets the innerText of title and checks if this value exists in another table. Something like this:

```
private void TestTitleExist(string innerTextTitle)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=;Password=");
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select 'x' from titles where lower(title) = :@title", conn);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title",innerTextTitle);
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
              if (reader.Read())
              {
                 Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}",reader["title"]));
               }
            }

            conn.Close();
        }
```

After debugging this method, the innerText title is being passed into this method.
For some reason, this query is returning empty even though this title exists in the titles table.
If I run the query directly in SQL server:

```
select 'x' from titles where title = 'This is the title'
```

I get 0 rows. But if I remove the white spaces from the title itself (This is the title) and add the spaces back in manually and run the query I get 1 row as expected. It seems like the actual spaces in the titles are adding some kind of formatting. Any idea?

Comment: Unicode has several "space" characters beyond the standard `U+0020`, in category Zs "Separator, Space".  For a list see here: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm.  You might check to see whether the `innerTextTitle` or the textual data stored in the server use less-than-conventional space characters.

Comment: You might also check to see whether either string has nonprinting characters in the Cc "Other, Control" category, https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Cc/list.htm

Comment: Why is your connection string "DataSource" empty?  You may be using a different mdf file in SQL Server than in your c# code.

Comment: Regarding unicode, what am I actually looking for here (i'm a newbie)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use XML data type column for any data in XML format.

Please try the following conceptual example for your exact scenario.

It covers just SQL Server side. All you need to do is to call its SQL statement. The idea is very simple:

- Convert `NTEXT` data type into `XML` data type.
- Query XML data by using powerful XQuery methods available in SQL Server.

Casting as `xs:token` does the following 'magic':

1. All invisible TAB, Carriage Return, and Line Feed characters will be
   replaced with spaces.
2. Then leading and trailing spaces are removed from the value.
3. Further, contiguous occurrences of more than one space will be
   replaced with a single space.

**SQL #1**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata  NTEXT);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<data>
    <id>123</id>
    <title>This is the title</title>
</data>'),
(N'<data>
    <id>123</id>
    <title>This is NOT the title</title>
</data>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS 
(
    SELECT ID, TRY_CAST(xmldata AS XML) AS xmldata
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT * 
FROM rs
WHERE rs.xmldata.exist('/data[title/text()="This is the title"]') = 1;
```

**Output**

```
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| ID |                          xmldata                          |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | <data><id>123</id><title>This is the title</title></data> |
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

**SQL #2**

Second scenario covers embedded white spaces in the XML.

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata  NTEXT);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<data>
    <id>123</id>
    <title>This    is the title   </title>
</data>'),
(N'<data>
    <id>123</id>
    <title>This is NOT the title</title>
</data>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS 
(
    SELECT ID, TRY_CAST(xmldata AS XML) AS xmldata
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT * 
FROM rs
WHERE rs.xmldata.exist('/data[string((title/text())[1]) cast as xs:token? eq "This is the title"]') = 1;
```

**Output**

```
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID |                            xmldata                             |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | <data><id>123</id><title>This   is the title   </title></data> |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I'd rather this be a C# solution. Not able to change data type of this column

Comment: @user3596206, (1) I showed how to cast current NTEXT data type to XML for both solutions. So it is not a problem. (2) If you wish, you can package T-SQL side as a stored procedure. Just call it from the c# and pass a parameter for a string to search.

Comment: My issue is more with if I paste this into SQL Server Management Studio 
    select 'x' from titles where title = 'This is the title'
It returns 0 but if I then remove the spaces between "This is the title" and add the spaces back in the query returns 1 record which is correct. This is what puzzles me more. Passing the title in from the C# code to the SQL is causing the same issue. Any idea on why this might be happening ?

Comment: @user3596206, the SQL #2 is your answer. It strips all the visible as well as invisible whitespace characters via `xs:token` from the `<title>This    is the title   </title>` XML element, and gives a correct result.